# Reimplementing QStyledItemDelegate::paint - How to obtain subelement coordinates?

Tags: c++, ruby, qt

A **QTreeView** is rendered with the help of a custom `QStyledItemDelegate::paint` method. The intention is to add graphical elements to the nodes, e.g. to draw (and fill) a box around the item texts. The tree items may have check boxes, or not.

The Ruby code below achieves the goal, except that I cannot obtain the coordinates of the text element. An empirical offset (x=29; y=4) serves as a workaround. The `super` method draws the text on top of the box.

- How can I obtain the **coordinates of the text element**?
- Is this the right approach at all, or do I have to use *drawText* and *drawControl* instead of calling the superclass *paint* method? In that case, how do you control the layout of the sub elements?

(This question is not Ruby specific. Answers containing C++ are welcome.)

```
class ItemDelegate < Qt::StyledItemDelegate

  def paint(painter, option, index)

    text     = index.data.toString
    bg_color = Qt::Color.new(Qt::yellow)
    fg_color = Qt::Color.new(Qt::black)
    offset   = Qt::Point.new(29,4)

    painter.save
    painter.translate(option.rect.topLeft + offset)

    recti = Qt::Rect.new(0, 0, option.rect.width, option.rect.height)
    rectf = Qt::RectF.new(recti)

    margin      = 4
    bounding    = painter.boundingRect(rectf, Qt::AlignLeft, text)
    tbox        = Qt::RectF.new(Qt::PointF.new(-margin,0), bounding.size)
    tbox.width += 2*margin

    painter.fillRect(tbox, bg_color)
    painter.drawRect(tbox)
    painter.restore

    super
  end
end
```

---

**Edit:** Please find a [self-contained example here in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/bogl2016/8c9398656dd5ed041947).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in C++. Unfortunately, the workaround on option.rect.* properties seems to be the only way to find the text coords.

Here the paint method of my delegate:

```
 void ThumbnailDelegate::paint(QPainter *p_painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &p_option, const QModelIndex &p_index) const
 {
    if(p_index.isValid())
    {
        const QAbstractItemModel* l_model = p_index.model();
        QPen l_text_pen(Qt::darkGray);

        QBrush l_brush(Qt::black, Qt::SolidPattern);

        /** background rect **/
        QPen l_pen;
        l_pen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
        l_pen.setWidth(4);
        l_pen.setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
        l_pen.setCapStyle(Qt::RoundCap);
        l_pen.setJoinStyle(Qt::RoundJoin);

        p_painter->setPen(l_pen);

        QRect l_border_rect;
        l_border_rect.setX(p_option.rect.x() + 5);
        l_border_rect.setY(p_option.rect.y() + 5);
        l_border_rect.setWidth(p_option.rect.width() - 16);
        l_border_rect.setHeight(p_option.rect.height() - 16);

        QPainterPath l_rounded_rect;
        l_rounded_rect.addRect(QRectF(l_border_rect));
        p_painter->setClipPath(l_rounded_rect);

        /** background color for hovered items **/
        p_painter->fillPath(l_rounded_rect, l_brush);
        p_painter->drawPath(l_rounded_rect);

        /** image **/
        QPixmap l_pixmap = bytearrayToPixmap(l_model->data(p_index, ImageRole).toByteArray()).scaled(150, 150, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

        QRect l_img_rect = l_border_rect;

        int l_img_x = (l_img_rect.width()/2 - l_pixmap.width()/2)+l_img_rect.x();

        l_img_rect.setX(l_img_x);
        l_img_rect.setY(l_img_rect.y() + 12);
        l_img_rect.setWidth(l_pixmap.width());
        l_img_rect.setHeight(l_pixmap.height());
        p_painter->drawPixmap(l_img_rect, l_pixmap);

        /** label **/
        QRect l_txt_rect = p_option.rect;
        l_txt_rect.setX(l_border_rect.x()+5);
        l_txt_rect.setY(l_border_rect.y() + l_border_rect.height() -20);
        l_txt_rect.setHeight(20);
        l_txt_rect.setWidth(l_txt_rect.width()-20);

        QFont l_font;
        l_font.setBold(true);
        l_font.setPixelSize(12);
        p_painter->setFont(l_font);
        p_painter->setPen(l_text_pen);

        QString l_text = l_model->data(p_index, TextRole).toString();
        p_painter->drawText(l_txt_rect, Qt::ElideRight|Qt::AlignHCenter, l_text);
    }
    else
    {
        qWarning() << "ThumbnailDelegate::paint() Invalid index!";
    }
}
```

I am not skilled on Ruby but, as you can see, I am using drawPath, drawPixmap and drawText.

Here is the result:

[image]

I think it is better to avoid invoking paint from the superclass, since it should be done automatically by Qt and you *may* break something on the UI lifecycle.